# Integration of the product of zeta function and gamma function

Tags: calculus, analytic-number-theory, gamma-function, riemann-zeta

I'm considering the complex integration

$$
\int_{\sigma=-1+\epsilon} |\zeta^2(1+2s)\Gamma(s)|\mathrm{d}s,
$$

where $s=\sigma+i\tau$, $\sigma,\tau \in \mathbb R$. Since the zeta function increase polynomially if $\sigma$ is uniformly bounded and the gamma function decrease exponentially by the Stirling's formula, I believe this integration does not diverge i.e. it has a finite value. However, I couldn't prove my claim rigorously.

Comment: Sure $\zeta(s) =-s\int_1^\infty \{x\}x^{-s-1}dx = O(|s|)$ on $\Re(s)=2\epsilon$ on the other hand $\Gamma(s) =\frac{\Gamma(s+m+1)}{\prod_{j=0}^m (s+j)}\le \frac{\Gamma(\sigma+m+1)}{\prod_{j=0}^m |s+j|}$. That being said I doubt you have good reason to look at such an integral with $|\Gamma(s)|$, did you mean $\int_{\sigma=-1+\epsilon} |\zeta^2(1+2s)\Gamma(s)|^2\mathrm{d}s,$

Comment: reuns // The reason I look at this is little bit complicated, but I just mention that the question is right and I need to see such integral to proceed the reading of certain papers (Jutila's 1980 paper and so on)